# How to center a text view with Applescript Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, applescript, applescript-objc, applescript-studio

I have a simple text view (which is inside a scroll view) and for the life of me I cannot make it center the text inside the text view. There is no choice in the inspector to center the text like there is when you use a normal text field. I have tried stuff like:

```
tell textView to setTextAlignment_(current application's setTextAlignment UITextAlignmentCenter)
```

But, obviously that fails. How is this done?

Comment: Did you mean `setAlignment_()`? There is no `setTextAlignment:` selector on `NSText` or `NSTextView`.

Comment: In non-programming speak all I need to know is how to center text programatically in a textView, which inside a scroll view. New to ObjC, heavy Applescript Studio user.

Comment: UITextAlignment is an iOS paradigm. If it exists you are after an NSTextAlignment value.

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
tell textView to setAlignment_(current application's NSTextAlignmentCenter)
```